# Input on change event not getting called when change

Tags: reactjs, events, input, antd

I'm using [antd](https://ant.design/components/input-number/) for my number input and I'm trying to call the `onChange` method when the input changes. The problem is the event doesn't get called when the user backspaces all the way, i.e. when the input is empty.

```
<InputNumber type="number" onChange={(val) => onChange(val)} />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-http-zq0ue?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It does trigger when the input blurs but not before then if it's empty.

Comment: @fast-reflexes Ya, but I need it to be on empty before the blur. How can I do that

Comment: Try other even handlers, like `onKeyDown` as suggested below or look into the implementation of antd `InputNumber` to figure out why it doesn't trigger ... because it is certainly not the expected behaviour ... maybe file a bug report with them if you think that their component is malfunctioning!

Answer (score 0):

Found another alternative in `InputNumber` component. Use `onInput` would capture input even if the input field is empty but it should work together with `onStep` to capture up or down buttons click event.

```
<InputNumber type="number" onInput={(val) => onChange(val)} onStep={(val) => onChange(val)} />
```

**Note:** 
`onInput` return string value
`onStep` return number value
NaN input (e.g operator sign) is read as empty string